# Leibniz Integration Rule

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Can anything be said of the following expression? $$\frac{\partial{}}{\partial{\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{g(\pi)}v(s_1,s_2)f(s_1|s_2)ds_1$$

$f(s_1|s_2)$ is a conditional pdf, however I'm not sure that's relevant to answer the question I'm pondering. In the course of a project I stumbled upon this expression and wonder if anything can be simplified. I've been looking for ways to apply Leibniz's Integration rule however I do not think I can because the lower bound is infinite. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't have to go so far as invoking Leibniz, this is just the second fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: The second fundamental theorem of calculus requires that the lower bound of integration is a constant so how would I do that? Also I integrate to a function of $\pi$ not $\pi$ itself.

Comment: Since this is a pdf you are assuming some degree of regularity anyway - which means you treat $-\infty$ as a constant. But you are integrating to some variable $f$, meaning you can do $\frac{d}{df}$ directly. How do you then get the derivative you want?

Comment: Sorry I think I see the confusion, it was a notation issue - the upper limit is not the same function $f$ as the pdf. And the integrand is not a pdf, however $f(s_1|s_2)$ is a pdf. So how do I differentiate such an expression?

Comment: Give it your best attempt and post what you think the answer would be with the second FTC and I'll help you. Pattern matching formulae is an important skill to cultivate. The time for questions is over and the time for action is now! :) As a hint though nothing in the integrand should be differentiated in your final answer.

Comment: Instead of $g^{-1}$ it should just be $g$. Other than it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{g(\pi)}v(s_1,s_2)f(s_1|s_2)ds_1 = \frac{\partial}{\partial\pi}\int_{-\infty}^0v(s_1,s_2)f(s_1|s_2)ds_1 + \frac{\partial}{\partial\pi}\int_0^{g(\pi)}v(s_1,s_2)f(s_1|s_2)ds_1\\
= 0 + \frac{\partial}{\partial\pi}\int_0^{g(\pi)}v(s_1,s_2)f(s_1|s_2)ds_1$$

The integral from $-\infty$ to $0$ does not change with $\pi$, so it is constant, and its derivative is $0$.

I.e., assuming that the integral from $-\infty$ exists, you can consider $-\infty$ as a constant.